# Upgrade from Babel 6 to 7 and receive a "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type..." error?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, vue-loader

I've been stuck on this issue for days. It started when I was trying to use the [Uppload-Vue](https://uppload.js.org/) package but kept receiving an error:

[image: You may need an appropriate loader error]

I started digging into their code and realized that they were using Babel 7 and I was still using 6, so I decided I may as well try to upgrade. Using the babel upgrade tool, I moved up to Babel 7, and fixed a few other unrelated errors but now I'm finally back to where I started with the same exact original error!

My question is, is this an issue with their package in some way? Or is my webpack not set up correctly?

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: file => (
          /node_modules/.test(file) &&
          !/\.vue\.js/.test(file)
        )
      },
      {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new Dotenv(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  externals: {
    // global app config object
    config: JSON.stringify({
      apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    }),
  },
}
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-root-import",
      {
        "rootPathSuffix": "src/",
        "rootPathPrefix": "~"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator",
      {
        "proposal": "minimal"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, apparently removing the `exclude: /(node_modules)/,` line from the vue loader fixed it. Why do we do this to ourselves?